# Angular return value promise function

Tags: angular, function

i have the following function, which i would like to return the value. It doesn`t return anything. I`m starting with Angular, so this is new for me.. how can i fix it?

```
        function GetAuth2Token(device) 
        {
           QRC.setTargetIpAddress(device.ip, device.index);
           QRC.getToken(vm.current_password ||'12345678', device.index).then(sucFn);
        function sucFn(data) {
            QRC.setTargetAuthToken(data.data.access_token);
            return data.data.access_token;
        }
    }
```

And then, when i call the function:

```
                var access_token = GetAuth2Token(vm.scannedDevices[i]);
```

But it doesn`t work, it does not return anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
var access_token;
GetAuth2Token(vm.scannedDevices[i]).then(function(data){
    access_token = data; 
});
```

Comment: sorry, but, what should i do with the rest of the code?

Comment: ı dont know others parts but you are returning promise but your function doesnt wait until resolved.

Comment: I mean.. i have the definition of the function with the promise, with more code that you suggested me.. that code i mean..

Comment: it can be same.

Comment: what you recommended, was for the definition of the function? Or the calling? Because i did it for calling it, and say: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Can you try like this ?

Comment: I did, it returnsa promise object, which this structure: Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}. Is it possible to return just de value? Thanks and sorry for my questions..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148450/discussion-between-nazir-dogan-and-mati-silver).

Comment: if i want to use access_token outside the function, it is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148501/discussion-between-mati-silver-and-nazir-dogan).

Comment: Are you still here?